# React - What is the best way to handle login and authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

New to react and working on an application with authentication/logging in. It currently works but feels hacked together. Right now I have my `isAuthenticated` state located in my `routes.js` like so:

```
class Routes extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
         }
     }
```

On my login page, I need to know when a user is authenticated to redirect them to the `home` page. What is the best design pattern to allow access and manipulation of this `isAuthenticated` state? How I currently have it set up is I have a function that sets the state inside the `routes.js` and sends the state as a prop like so:

```
 setAuthenticated = (isAuthenticated) => {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated});
    }
```

and down below in the router...

```
<Route path="/" exact component={() =>
                            <div>
                                <Login
                                    isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                                    setAuthenticated={this.setAuthenticated}
                            </div>
                        } />
```

Yes, I understand this is bad design because this is changing props values which are supposed to be immutable. This is also bad because when I change this value in my `login.js` it causes multiple unnecessary re-renders. Should I be declaring `isAuthenticated` as some type of global variable? I am not using any state management by the way.

Edit: I am setting `isAuthenticated` based on a response from my server which confirms correct login/password combination.

Comment: If your page protection relies on an 'isAuthenticated' state variable, you should probably [disable the react devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783620/disable-chrome-react-devtools-for-production) in production. Otherwise, it would be possible to inspect the page and manually flip the flag to true, exposing the protected page to an unauthenticated user.

Comment: @bje No security stuff should be implemented on the front-end side. Things like redirecting user to home page and ... are just for better UX not strict security rules

Answer (score 148):

Handling `isAuthenticated` **only in the `state`** means the user will be unauthenticated every time he refreshes the page. That's not really user-friendly! :)

So instead, the Login page should **store an `access_token`** (coming from your backend) **in the [`cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) of the browser**. An `access_token` proves the user is authenticated and also verifies his identity. You will usually pass this `access_token` to every next requests to your server, to check if this user is allowed to access the data he's requesting, or allowed to create, edit and delete the things he's trying to create, edit and delete.

Then you can check this `access_token` on every other pages as well and redirect the user to the Login page if he's not authenticated anymore.

---

A brief aside on the difference between **`access_token`** and **`refresh_token`** – *this will help you understand the code bellow, but feel free to skip ahead if you are already familiar with it*.

Your backend probably uses [`OAuth2`](https://oauth.net), which is the most common authentication protocol nowadays. With `OAuth2`, your app makes a first request to the server containing the username and password of the user to authenticate. Once the user is authenticated, he receives 1) an `access_token`, which usually expires after an hour, and 2) a `refresh_token`, which expires after a very long time (hours, days). When the `access_token` expires, instead of asking the user for his username and password again, your app sends the `refresh_token` to the server to obtain a new `access_token` for this user.

---

A brief aside on the differences between **`cookies`** and **`localStorage`** – *feel free to skip it too!*

`localStorage` is the most recent technology between both. It's a simple key/value persistence system, which seems perfect to store the `access_token` and its value. But we also need to persist its date of expiration. We could store a second key/value pair named `expires` but it would be more logic to handle on our side.

On the other hand, `cookies` have a native `expires` property, which is exactly what we need! `cookies` are an old technology and are not very developer-friendly, so I personally use [`js-cookie`](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), which is a small library to manipulate `cookies`. It makes it look like a simple key/value persistence system too: `Cookies.set('access_token', value)` then `Cookies.get('access_token')`.

Other pro for the `cookies`: they are cross [subdomains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)! If your Login app is `login.mycompany.com` and your Main app is `app.mycompany.com`, then you can create a `cookie` on the Login app and access it from the Main app. This is not possible with `LocalStorage`.

---

Here are some of the methods and special React components I use for authentication:

## isAuthenticated()

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const getAccessToken = () => Cookies.get('access_token')
export const getRefreshToken = () => Cookies.get('refresh_token')
export const isAuthenticated = () => !!getAccessToken()
```

## authenticate()

```
export const authenticate = async () => {
  if (getRefreshToken()) {
    try {
      const tokens = await refreshTokens() // call an API, returns tokens

      const expires = (tokens.expires_in || 60 * 60) * 1000
      const inOneHour = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expires)

      // you will have the exact same setters in your Login page/app too
      Cookies.set('access_token', tokens.access_token, { expires: inOneHour })
      Cookies.set('refresh_token', tokens.refresh_token)

      return true
    } catch (error) {
      redirectToLogin()
      return false
    }
  }

  redirectToLogin()
  return false
}
```

## redirectToLogin()

```
const redirectToLogin = () => {
  window.location.replace(
    `${getConfig().LOGIN_URL}?next=${window.location.href}`
  )
  // or history.push('/login') if your Login page is inside the same app
}
```

## AuthenticatedRoute

```
export const AuthenticatedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  exact,
  path,
}) => (
  <Route
    exact={exact}
    path={path}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <AuthenticateBeforeRender render={() => <Component {...props} />} />
      )
    }
  />
)
```

## AuthenticateBeforeRender

```
class AuthenticateBeforeRender extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    authenticate().then(isAuthenticated => {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.isAuthenticated ? this.props.render() : null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the well rounded answer. I am setting `isAuthenticated` after authenticated on my server and sending an ok response. So after I get a good authentication response I should store it in localStorage like the first answer suggests, correct?

Comment: You probably need a token from your server. When your app will call your server APIs to retrieve some data, you want to pass a header `Authorization: token` in each request to prove the identity of the author of the request.

Comment: Since you're accessing the cookies from the code, it means they are not HttpOnly, does that mean a CSS vulnerability is present?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache Yes, this method is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Auth cookies should be http only, this answer is bad bad bad.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache No, there are no XSS attack vectors in this answer and the examples I posted. – If your app is vulnerable to XSS attacks, indeed an attacker could steal cookies as well as anything else (passwords, emails, phone and credit card numbers, etc.). You should probably audit and review your code if you think your app is vulnerable to these attacks. Here are some resources about how to prevent them: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss. I also recommend you to check this answer about some XSS attack vectors in React (with examples): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852579/652669

Comment: This is indeed a dangerous and insecure way to store authentication tokens. Cookies can be set with an `HTTPOnly` flag which exists specifically to limit the damage an  XSS attack can cause. Your response is hyperbolic in the extreme: An XSS vulnerability in a webapp does *not* let it steal cookies, *if they are properrly secured*, which they are not in your example, and claiming XSS can steal "passwords, emails, phone and credit card numbers" is absurd. The fact is this answer is dangerously insecure; your front-end JS should not be handling auth tokens.

Comment: Note that your own links to OWASP recommend using HTTPOnly cookies, which is impossible if your setting the cookie via JS, which you are doing: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#bonus-rule-1-use-httponly-cookie-flag

Comment: Also note: It is extremely incorrect and dangerous to expose the `refresh_token` to the browser, which you also appear to be doing. This is a *massive* no-no in OAuth2, and it shouldn't even be possible, since it seems like you're using the implicit flow, which usually cannot issue refresh tokens for this very reason.

Comment: @meagar I feel like you took this answer out of context (and I know you are here only because I flagged a comment). The question is about React single page applications (SPAs). My answer is for a scenario where all the requests between the SPA and the server go through a REST API. Now each request requires an `Authorization` header containing an access token, which I need to store somewhere. The most secure thing to do would be to store the token only in memory (a JS variable in the app). Problem is, the users will have to log in again every time they refresh the page or open a new tab.

Comment: @meagar  This is a _massive_ no-no for most users, so I need to store the token somewhere else to persist the "session". Even if I could store the token in a `HTTPOnly` cookie, I won't be able to read its value (JavaScript can't access it). So my only options are localStorage, JS cookies (which I both compare in my answer) and other browser storage technologies. I think (and lots of people, since it's a pretty common pattern with SPAs to store tokens in browser storage) this trade off between security and user-experience is OK with proper XSS preventions and token expiration on the server.

Comment: @meagar Here are some links about this topic: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/175785/26797, https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179507/26797, https://security.stackexchange.com/a/220059/26797, https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/bpcleu/so_whats_the_issue_with_jwts_in_localstorage, https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/token-storage#browser-in-memory-scenarios, https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/README.md#tokengetter-function. Also, I'm going to check what you said about the `refresh_token` and update my answer if you are right!

Comment: @GG., thanks for the really helpful and thorough answer! Could you please recommend a JS library / package that implements an authentication strategy like the one proposed in your answer?

Comment: @ezpresso For React? Surprisingly, I don't think there are any reputable libraries with components and/or hooks for authentication. Seems like everybody is (re)implementing its own homemade solution.

Comment: @GG. Oh, thanks! That's really surprising. What about any general purpose authentication libraries for JS / Node? Anything other than Passport.js.

Comment: What's the consensus here on this approach's security in 2022?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using an application where the authentication lasts only for one session, storing it in state is enough. 
But do note that this means, the user will lose the authenticated status on page refresh.

Here is an example using React Context, where we create context using `createContext` and use `Consumer` to access it across the application.

```js
const AuthenticationContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider, Consumer } = AuthenticationContext;

function Login(props) {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>
        <button onClick={value.login}>Login</button>
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

function Logout() {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>
        <button onClick={value.logout}>Logout</button>
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

function AnotherComponent() {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>{
          return value.isAuthenticated?
            <p>Logged in</p>:
            <p>Not Logged in</p>
        }
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = ()=> {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true
      });
    }
    this.logout = ()=> {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false
      });
    }
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      login: this.login,
      logout: this.logout
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state}>
        <Login />
        <Logout />
        <AnotherComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

Answer (score 4):

you can set the access token in the local storage on login and clear it after the user logs out. the is authenticated method will then be used to check if there is a token and whether the token is valid while making an API call

Comment: Okay, a more general question. What if I need to also manage other properties along with `isAuthenticated` such as `isAdmin` or `accountId`?

Comment: @VincentNguyen you can use JWT.

Answer (score -4):

One of the best ways to use the `React-Auth-Kit` library. It has all the features, that can be used with react.

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-auth-kit

Comment: If you made this, you should clarify that.