# i need to change the login to add to cart when the user login in react

Tags: reactjs

is their any possible way to change the state of header that track the user is logged in or not and show the button as per it if login in then show add to cart and if not show login

i have checked the session storage where i have stored my data if their is data change the state if not don't  in component did mount but the component did mount will not re render the app we have to do manual refresh how to keep track of it

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';


class Header extends React.Component {

    state = {
        login: false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const data = sessionStorage.getItem("login");
        if (data) {
            this.setState({ login: !this.state.login })
        }

    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.login !== this.state.login) {
            this.setState({ login: true })
        }

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <NavLink to="/" >Home</NavLink>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle />
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav>
                        <LinkContainer to="/shop">
                            <NavItem eventKey={1}>Shop</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        {this.state.login ?
                            <LinkContainer to="/addtocart">
                                <NavItem eventKey={1}>Add To cart</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                            :
                            <LinkContainer to="/login">
                                <NavItem eventKey={1}>Login</NavItem>
                            </LinkContainer>
                        }

                        <LinkContainer to="/signip">
                            <NavItem eventKey={1}>Sigup</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>

                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}



export default Header;
```

and in login

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { UserData } from '../../PostData';
import { ClipLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        loading: false,
        redirect: false
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        if (this.state.email && this.state.email !== '') {
            try {
                UserData(this.state.username, this.state.email).then(result => {

                    this.setState({ loading: false })
                    if (result.length) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify(result));
                        this.setState({ redirect: true })
                    } else {
                        alert("please enter the write email and username");
                    }

                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        } else {
            console.log("black")
        }

    }
    onChangeHandle = (e) => {

        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '50%', zIndex: '111111' }}>
                    <ClipLoader
                        sizeUnit={"px"}
                        size={150}
                        color={'#123abc'}
                        loading={this.state.loading}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup
                            controlId="formBasicText"
                        // validationState={this.getValidationState()}
                        >
                            <ControlLabel>username</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter username"
                                name="username"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />

                            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="login"></input>

                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Login;
`
import React from 'react';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { UserData } from '../../PostData';
import { ClipLoader } from 'react-spinners';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class Login extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        loading: false,
        redirect: false
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        if (this.state.email && this.state.email !== '') {
            try {
                UserData(this.state.username, this.state.email).then(result => {

                    this.setState({ loading: false })
                    if (result.length) {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("login", JSON.stringify(result));
                        this.setState({ redirect: true })
                    } else {
                        alert("please enter the write email and username");
                    }

                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        } else {
            console.log("black")
        }

    }
    onChangeHandle = (e) => {

        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '50%', zIndex: '111111' }}>
                    <ClipLoader
                        sizeUnit={"px"}
                        size={150}
                        color={'#123abc'}
                        loading={this.state.loading}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup
                            controlId="formBasicText"
                        // validationState={this.getValidationState()}
                        >
                            <ControlLabel>username</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter username"
                                name="username"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />

                            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                            <FormControl
                                type="text"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter email"
                                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
                            />
                            <FormControl.Feedback />
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="login"></input>

                        </FormGroup>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Login;
`
```

Comment: Keep state of login in context and render accordingly?

Comment: is their any possible way we can do with component lifecycle instead of using context api

Comment: Well, it can be done. Keep the state in App component for login and pass it as prop to Header. But better with context anyway

Comment: can u please give me a hint of code  how to change state from login false to login true through context i know how to get the state from context but i have not tried to check from sessionstorage and change the state

Comment: You don't have to set it from session storage, just set it in the login component itself

Comment: sorry i did not get it can u provide snip shot of that code i really need it for my project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819819/4374566