# What's a secure way to store token & auth state?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, jwt, local-storage, token

Here's my scenario:

When a user logs in, an API call is made and if his credentials are valid, a token is returned. I need to store the authentication state (to keep the user logged in) and the token somewhere. The token will be used to make other API calls.

I've read these posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819183/react-what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-login-and-authentication), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420531/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-a-users-session-in-react), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176237/how-do-i-store-jwt-and-send-them-with-every-request-using-react) (and some others) which all seem to contradict each other; whether it's `localStorage`, `cookies` or `JWT`, all are being deemed as unsafe by different people. I have also read about `react-redux` too but I'm not sure about it.

For now I am completely lost on which solution best suits my needs since I am new to `reactJs`. So, what is the proper way to go on about this?

Comment: Redux is orthogonal; it's just a state management tool. The "proper" way depends; "a token" is somewhat vague. API calls to who? *Your* app? External apps?

Comment: @DaveNewton each user is assigned a token. This token will be used for the API calls to the backend which will fetch data to be displayed on the different pages of the react app

Comment: Simple answer use `cookies`. `JWT`'s isn't supposed to be used to store tokens and `localStorage` isn't safe. I'm struggling with implementing cookies on reactjs as well.

Comment: @Tony yes, i finally used `cookies`. I used `js-cookie` (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). If you are having trouble, check it out; it is really simple to use

Comment: @jo12345678 finally something that works. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common practice is storing your token in cookie and set `HttpOnly` to `true`, so that any javascript code cannot read your token programmatically.

I suppose you are using `axios` as ajax client, you can make a request like this

```
axios.get('https://example.com/api', {
  withCredentials: true
})
```

by doing this, `axios` will send your cookies to remote server automatically